# IE10 developer tool cause style missing

Tags: css, internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools

I have a page1 including page2 with "iframe" tag,both of these two pages link to the same stylesheet,everything works fine,until i press "F12" to toggle developer tool in IE10,some of the classes miss styles defined in the css file suddenly,and the two pages go into a wrong display. Can anyone help?

there are two methods to solve this problem, change the class name or add a timestamp after style url. Why?

Comment: In my case the style have problems and the site look&feel is completely wrong. Did you find the solution to this problem?

Comment: sorry,not yet,i haven't got the answer why this happened

Comment: We have the very same problem at nk.pl - we have an iframe and parent link to the same stylesheet (buttons.css in our case) and once I press F12 the 'x' buttons in the parent loose their styles. Also, when refreshing the page with F12 tools opened, there is a short moment when you can actually see the 'x' but after that it disappears.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in IE10.

You can add a query string in `page2` to fix this bug:

**page2:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css?t=2013" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css?t=2013" />
```

**page1:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" />
```

Comment: I've run into this problem with iframe linking to the same CSS as the parent page and IE10 Dev Tools rendering the page badly. This did work thanks, however I'm personally going to see if I can avoid loading the CSS in both places.

Comment: thx,i've mentioned this solution in my description.i just wonder more